# How do I intergrate a html document into the code

Tags: html, android, eclipse-plugin

I am currently working on a new app and this is my first ever app I have attemped to make with the android os.

I am using eclipse 3.6 and using android 1.5 version as the base to make the app as compatible as I can with all android phones.

I am a newbie to java and I read a few tutorials which helped me get the app up and working but I am using webview using iframes and have the html document hosted online but I would like to have it intergrated into the app itself so that I will not have to worry if a lot of people use the app will not bring down the website.

But I also want it to be able to update all the data off the website when members want to check for updated information on the html document as I am using the html document to control the main gui.

Comment: Why not have all the displaying programs as part of the application and only download the data needed from the website? Honestly, displaying a webpage as an application isn't really an application. It's a web browser that can only access one website... Not to mention I don't want to download that entire HTML file every update when I could just download the information and use the files already on my phone, much faster. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: The update feature is just for checking the data for changes and judt download the changes to data not just downloads everything but right now it may just be easyer to just manually update the information the just upload a new version of the app then. The html document is just easyer for the tutorial but unless there is something I can use to convert the html document into a java based gui because it is a tutorial the my group wrote for the program this guide covers.

Answer (score 0):

please use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/start#android), this will fulfil your requirements